# Webview Url load from plist file

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS. I set the url in webview from a plist file. Below code is in objective C.

What would be the same on Swift?`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];       
[_webView loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"webViewURL"]]]];`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("YourPlistName", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath!)
webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: dict?.objectForKey("webViewURL") as! String)!))
```

Comment: Error :Can not convert value of AnyObject to expected argument type string

Comment: try the update above, I have fixed it. I guess Xcode would automatically help you to fix such issues right??

Comment: @tushar kindly upvote or accept if the answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equivalent code :

```
var webview: UIWebView?

func loadwebView() {
    if let plist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist"),
        let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plist),
        let urlString = plistDict.objectForKey("webViewURL") as? String,
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {

            webview?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }
}
```